# RewriteRule issue with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^Service/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ /service/index.php?action=$1
```

However, when I open `localhost/Service/Test/`, it gives me a 404 error.

Strangely, opening `localhost/Service/` successfully loads `/service/index.php` with empty action parameter. I simply can't understand this behaviour.

Could you explain me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

**Edit**: opening `/service/index.php` manually works fine.

**Edit2**: I uploaded it to a free webhosting service and it works perfectly there. There must be some error in my Apache config (I'm using XAMPP by the way).

Comment: Is there some CMS/PHP framework running in `/service/` folder?

Comment: Nope, there is only the index.php inside.

Comment: So `/service/index.php?action=test` works fine?

Comment: Does `/service/` has a .htaccess file by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is only one file, index.php within.

Comment: are there more rules in this root .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, they work fine. For debugging, I have disabled all of them but this one and the result remained the same.

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately, I get the same result :(

Comment: Is `localhost/Service/foo/` also giving 404?

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
RewriteBase /
```

before RewriteRule

[check the doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Comment: my guess is because both the rule and the folder have the same name,
Service, can you change one of them ?
and keep Rewritebase / it is important also